# Some basic upshot questions

Tags: knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, upshot

I am new to MVC, SPA and all that. I follow this video:

http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechDays/TechDays-2012-Belgium/199

and I got stuck in the moment when it deals with upshot.

```
@{Html.UpshotContext().DataSource<DataServicesController>(x => x.GetDeliveriesForToday());}
```

What exactly does this do and what should I do if GetDeliveriesForToday accepts a parameter?

```
var dataSource = upshot.dataSources.DeliveriesForToday;
```

Secondly, what is `dataSources`? It is not found by VS2011 intellisense. And finally, where does `DeliveriesForToday` come from? The only thing which I can find is `GetDeliveriesForToday` function. Does that mean that upshot somehow automatically strips `Get`?